# where CSS cascades, so HTML inherits -- I don't quite get how "so" is used in this context

Tags: conjunctions, metaphors

> Inheritance describes situations where HTML elements inherit stylistic properties from a
>   parent element. By not declaring a particular CSS value for the child element, that child element may in some circumstances inherit the CSS value given to the parent element. Where CSS
>   cascades, **so** HTML inherits.

If we get rid of *so*, the sentence, at least to me, reads quite well: *where CSS cascades, HTML inherits*. That makes perfect sense. But I don't know how I should understand the sentence when that *so* is thrown into the mix. What meaning does it have then?

Comment: I think the author is conflating two distinct locutions that can mean pretty much the same thing: "where x does this, y does that" and "as x does this, so y does that". The as...so implies a kind of mirroring; the where-version can express mirroring but it could also express a contrary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the same thing in this context.

It is my understanding that the phrase is normally used in this syntax: "`<clause>`, so `<verb>` `<clause>`". The author has strayed from this convention by switching the positions of "HTML" (the subject) and "inherits" (the verb). Remember, "so" is also a conjunction. This is a more "conventional" example:

> Where CSS cascades, so does HTML inherit.

Or even:

> Where CSS cascades, so inherits HTML.

This is just the same thing as the original sentence with "HTML" and "inherits" switched.
If you're confused by this phrase, consider the following dialogue:

> "I usually like to go out for a jog before I go to work." "So do I."

This is probably familiar to you, right? The phrase "so does HTML inherit" replaces the subject of the sentence "So do I" with "HTML," and qualifies which action the HTML is "doing" with "inherit."

Comment: After seeing this post again upon noticing the alert for it in my inbox, I should add that "Where CSS cascades, so inherits HTML." isn't fully correct because it doesn't obey parallelism; I was just using it to show the similarities between the phrase structure. "CSS cascades" must be parallel to "HTML inherits" (subject, then verb)

Answer (score 2):

The cited usage is slightly uncommon - possibly because many native speakers feel the same as OP that there's something "not quite right" about the way ***so*** is used here. But I don't see anything wrong with it.

I suspect essentially OP's problem is that he understands ***so*** in such constructions to have the sense of ***in the same way*** (which semantically doesn't quite work in the *exact* cited context). But it can equally well carry other senses (as here) along the lines of ***in the same situation***, or ***for the same reason***.

In short, whilst it's true the sentence is perfectly grammatical (and indeed, more likely) *without* incluiding ***so***, there's nothing inherently "incorrect" about the cited usage.